# acts_as_votable one-to-many and only one option votable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rubygems

I'm trying to figure out how I can work with the acts_as_votable gem to implement a voting system with a one-to-many relationship. I have the `AgendaItem` model, which has-many `Conclusion` items. `Conclusion`s can be voted for by users, but they can only vote for one. If they vote for a second conclusion, it needs to change their vote.

Is there any way of implementing this without manually checking whether the user has already voted for a `conclusion` object? The documentation seems to cover simply voting on individual objects and doesn't cover a scenario similar to this unless I'm missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try patching `ActsAsVotable::Vote` to include [uniqueness validation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of) of the votes.

```
module ActsAsVotable
  class Vote < ::ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_uniqueness_of :voter_id, scope: [:votable_id],
      if: Proc.new { |vote| vote.votable_type == "Conclusion" && vote.voter_type == "User" }
  end
end
```

You will need to add unique index on :votable_type, :voter_type, :votable_id and :voter_id on the database to minimize performance penalty.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Would there also be a quick way of simply changing the vote from one to another without having to check each time? I guess that I'll have to implement myself?

Comment: You can call `User#vote_up` or `User#vote_down` as usual. Those methods call `Votable#vote`, which checks for existing votes and update the vote flag accordingly. Reference: [voter.rb](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable/blob/master/lib/acts_as_votable/voter.rb) and [votable.rb](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable/blob/master/lib/acts_as_votable/votable.rb)

Comment: Awesome :) I've added that module to my lib directory (and I have a require statement in an initializer) but when I check the Vote model for what validators it has, that one doesn't seem to have been added?

Comment: Have you figured this out? I'm trying to accomplish the same thing and have had zero luck...